# JavaFX - How to not show context menu of parent, if there is node above it

Tags: java, javafx, contextmenu

In my aplication I have a Pane, that has a context menu through which I can add an ImageView, for which I want to have a context menu as well.

Sadly when I request context menu for that ImageView, the one for Pane opens as well. How can I make it not appear without having to have only one ContextMenu object which I would give different MenuItems every time (does not seem very effective to me)
I am new to JavaFX so thanks for your patience.

[image: Two context menu's at once]

**Code:**

```
imgView.setOnContextMenuRequested(eventMenu -> {
            tableContextMenu.show(paneWorkspace, eventMenu.getSceneX(), eventMenu.getSceneY());
            if (paneContextMenu.isShowing()) {
                paneContextMenu.hide();
            }
        });
paneWorkspace.setOnContextMenuRequested(event ->
            paneContextMenu.show(paneWorkspace, event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY()));
```

*Note: `paneContextMenu.hide()` does not work*

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: Try `eventMenu.consume()`. If that doesn't work, create and post a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
I tried out *James_D*'s answer and it worked out. Thanks for sharing!
I called `eventMenu.consume()` anywhere in the lambda function and the other context menu doesn't pop out. 
Hovewer I find it pretty strange, since I call that in the ImageView's `setOnContextMenuRequest()` method and it consumes the other's one context menu.

**Changed code:**

```
table.setOnContextMenuRequested(eventMenu -> {
            eventMenu.consume();
            tableContextMenu.show(paneWorkspace, eventMenu.getSceneX(), eventMenu.getSceneY());
        });
paneWorkspace.setOnContextMenuRequested(event ->
            paneContextMenu.show(paneWorkspace, event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY())
    );
```

Comment: It consumes the event, preventing it from propagating to the node underneath.